2. Add Two Numbers in LeetCode
I made such a code, everything works correctly in Visual Studio Code, when transferring it to the LeetCode interpreter, it gives completely different results, why can this be?Thanks in advance for the reply.Link to the task:task
var addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2) {

// I determine the largest array of the two, then I will add the overall result to it

let big_array = (l1.length == l2.length) ? l1 : (l1.length>l2.length) ? l1 : l2
let small_array = (l1.length == l2.length) ? l2 : (l1.length>l2.length) ? l2 : l1

for(let i = 0; i < big_array.length ; i++){
    // I iterate over the array numbers and add them together in the big_array array.
   if(small_array[i] != undefined) big_array[i] += small_array[i]
        if(big_array[i] >= 9 && i == big_array.length-1){
            /*
            If the number in a certain place is greater than 0, then I will create a new array element in front of it, into which dozens from the previous element were stuffed and reduce it by these tens*10
            */
            big_array.push((big_array[i] - (big_array[i] % 10))/10)
            big_array[i] = big_array[i] % 10

        } else if(big_array[i] >= 9){
            // It's a similar procedure, but I won't create a new element, I'll just add it to an existing one
            big_array[i+1] +=  ((big_array[i] - (big_array[i] % 10))/10)
            big_array[i] = big_array[i] % 10
        }
    }
    return big_array
};

console.log("First test ",addTwoNumbers([2,4,3],[5,6,4])) 
console.log("Second test ",addTwoNumbers([0],[0])) 
console.log("Third test: ",addTwoNumbers([9,9,9,9,9,9,9],[9,9,9,9]) )

My Results in VSC and LeetCode
VSC
LeetCode testing
I tried to edit the code somehow and so on. I expect that everything will work the same way as I have in Visual Studio.

l1 and l2 are linked lists and not arrays.

Even though in LeetCode you see the inputs encoded in JSON, LeetCode will call your function with instances of ListNode. It clearly indicates this in the template code you got: @param {ListNode} l1, ...etc.
